# Proving Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

I have a $E[X_n] = p$ and $V[X_n] = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}$
and want to prove
$$ P(|X_n - p| \geq \alpha) \leq \frac{1}{4n\alpha^2} $$ for all $\alpha > 0$

Because $$ P(|X_n - p| \geq \alpha) \leq \frac{V[X_n]}{\alpha^2}$$
I tried proving by $$\frac{p(1-p)}{n\alpha^2} \leq \frac{1}{4n\alpha^2}$$
$$ V[X_n] \leq \frac{1}{4n}$$

I'm hoping that up to here my approach is correct but I'm not entirely sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Hint: what is the maximum of the function $f(p)=p(1-p)$?

Comment: @NapD.Lover would it be 1/4?

Comment: indeed so $p(1-p) \leq 1/4$ for all $0<p<1$ so dividing by $n$ and, etc etc…

Comment: @NapD.Lover oh gotcha the whole p being bigger than 0 and less than 1 makes a lot of sense.